# create STUN/TURN server on windows server 2012

Tags: webrtc, windows-server-2012, stun, turn

How can I create my on STUN/TURN server on Windows server 2012? I want to use that on webRTC project.

For now I'm using http://numb.viagenie.ca/ on my project, but that's very slow and can't use that on my project.

I searched on youtube but there is no tutorial video.

Comment: Google offers free services that are plenty fast

Answer (score 0):

You can try `gortcd` which is lightweight and written in go. Can even run on Win7.